# A characterization of reflections on Euclidean space

Tags: representation-theory, linear-algebra

In the book "Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation theory" by J. Humphreys page 42, the author proves the following lemma: Let $E$ be a finite dimensional Euclidean space over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb \phi\subseteq E$ be such that $\mathbb \phi $ spans $E.$ Suppose all reflections $\sigma_\alpha$,
$\alpha\in \mathbb \phi$ leave $\mathbb \phi$ invariant. If $\sigma\in GL(E)$ leaves $\mathbb \phi$ invariant, fixes pointwise a hyperplane $P$ and sends a nonzero $\alpha$ to $-\alpha,$ then $\sigma$ is nothing but the reflection $\sigma_\alpha$ around the hyperplane $P.$ Let $\sigma_\alpha$ be defined via $\sigma_\alpha(\beta):=\beta-\frac{2\langle\beta,\alpha\rangle}{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle}\alpha.$

He argues that for $\tau:=\sigma\sigma_\alpha^{-1},$ $\tau\mathbb \phi=\mathbb \phi.$ How is this true? Is it true that $\sigma\mathbb\phi\subseteq\mathbb\phi$ implies that $\sigma\mathbb\phi=\mathbb\phi$? Also, how to prove the rest of the lemma?

Comment: Certainly $\sigma$ is an automorphism, hence is injective on $\phi$, hence satisfies $\sigma \phi = \phi$ as you had hoped. Now notice that this forces $\tau$ to have finite order, hence be semi-simple. Its eigenvalues are all 1, hence it is the identity.

Comment: I still do not understand why $\sigma\phi=\phi.$ If the set $\phi$ consists of linearly independent elements, this is certainly true. What happens otherwise?

Comment: As $\sigma \in GL(E)$, we have $\sigma$ is injective as a set morphism $E \rightarrow E$. And as $\sigma\phi \subseteq \phi$, the restriction from $E$ to $\phi$ induces an injective set map $\phi \rightarrow \phi$, which is surjective since $\phi$ is finite.

Comment: The question doesn't say that $\phi$ is finite, but (as @ThomasChansler points out) Humphreys does; is that what you were missing?

Comment: Yes just for clarity a similar property fails for $\phi$ infinite, taking $E = \mathbb{R}$, $\phi = \mathbb{Z}$, and $\sigma: a \mapsto -2a$.

Comment: @ThomasChansler, your $\phi$ doesn't negate anything non-0.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: @ThomasChansler, sorry to be a pill, but it *still* doesn't negate anything non-0—I mean, it carries positive things to negative things, but never $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$ with $\alpha \ne 0$.

Comment: Why all eigen values of $\sigma$ are 1?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\tau$ (I think @GeordieWilliamson meant $\tau$ [everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310137/a-characterization-of-reflections-on-euclidean-space#comment6810307_3310137), not $\sigma$) are all 1 because it fixes $P$ pointwise (because both $\sigma$ and $\sigma_\alpha$ do), and fixes $\alpha$ (because both $\sigma$ and $\sigma_\alpha$ negate it), and $P$ and $\alpha$ together span.

Comment: Related" https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4227594/96384 and see links there.