# Help with a proof of a lemma from Humphreys about reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, lie-algebras, reflection, root-systems

I want to understand this proof, I don't get why he says that the minimal polinomial of $\tau$ divides $(T-1)^l$. And at the end how can I explain why gcd$(T^k-1,(T-1)^l)=T-1$?

[image]

Comment: That lemma of Humphreys seems to throw off many people! In https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4131835/96384, somebody did not understand why one has to do anything after the second line of the proof (the answer there exlains why); and in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4178348/96384, somebody missed the hypothesis that all $\sigma_\alpha$ leave $\Phi$ invariant, and then an answer pointed out a counterexample, however the step which the OP there doubted is actually true, and with that hypothesis the lemma works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all eigenvalues of $\tau$ are equal to $1$, then the matrix of $\tau$ with respect to some basis of $\mathrm E$ is upper triangular having only $1$'s in the main diagonal; therefore $(\tau-\operatorname{Id})^{\dim E}=0$, and so the minimal polynomial of $\tau$ has to divide $(T-1)^l$ (note that $l=\dim\mathrm E$).

On the other hand,$$T^k-1=(T-1)\left(T^{k-1}+T^{k-2}+\cdots+T+1\right)$$and $1$ is not a root of $T^{k-1}+T^{k-2}+\cdots+T+1$. Therefore, the only common factor of $T^k-1$ and $(T-1)^l$ is indeed $T-1$.

Comment: How do I know that the matrix of $\tau$ with respect to some basis of E is upper triangular?

Comment: Because that's true for *any* endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space. Are you aware of the Jordan normal form?

Comment: What I have is that any endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space that have caracteristical polinomial like $p(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{d_1}...(x-\lambda_n)^{d_n}$ have a jordan base, by saying that 1 is the only eigenvalues of $\tau$ then the caracteristic polinomial is mandatory  $p(x)=(x-1)^n$?

Comment: There is no such restriction over $\Bbb C$; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

Comment: Yes, but I'm not in $\mathbb{C}$, my $E$ is a euclidian space that is a real vector space, then I'm on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Lest time I checked, $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$. So, you cannot be on $\Bbb R$ without being on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Yes, but that's true for $\mathbb{C}$ because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and $\mathbb{R}$ is not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128713/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-121212).

Comment: Although it's very good to get used to arguing via complexification in such questions, one could also just extend $\alpha$ to any basis $\alpha=e_1,e_2, ..., e_l$ of $E$; then "$\tau$ acts as the identity on the subspace $\mathbb R \alpha$ as well as on the quotient $E/\mathbb R \alpha$" literally means that the matrix of $\tau$ w.r.t. this basis looks like $\pmatrix{1&*&*& *** & *\\ 0&1&0& \dots &0\\ 0&0&1& \dots &0\\\ &\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&0&\dots&1}$. It's hard to get more upper triangular than that, and quite obvious now that $(\tau- \mathrm{id})^l=0$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Indeed. Thank you.