# Can this linear algebra / geometry lemma in Humphreys be proven by induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, reflection, root-systems

[Many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227594/help-with-a-proof-of-a-lemma-from-humphreys-about-reflections?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131835/identity-on-hyperplane-and-its-complement-then-identity-on-whole-space-humphr?noredirect=1&lq=1) [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178348/linear-algebra-question-about-root-systems) [been](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310137/a-characterization-of-reflections-on-euclidean-space) asked on this site about the proof of Lemma 9.1 on page 42 of Humphreys's Lie algebra book. The full proof is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227594/help-with-a-proof-of-a-lemma-from-humphreys-about-reflections?noredirect=1&lq=1). I understand the proof, but I don't like it and would prefer a proof by induction. This seems plausible, since many results like this can be proven by induction, and induction on the dimension of $E$ looks promising. Can anyone offer a proof by induction of this result?

> **Lemma.** Let $\Phi$ be a finite set which spans $E$. Suppose all reflections $\sigma_\alpha$($\alpha \in \Phi$) leave $\Phi$ invariant. If $\sigma \in GL(E)$ leaves $\Phi$ invariant, fixes pointwise a hyperplane $P$ of $E$, and sends some nonzero $\alpha \in \Phi$ to its negative, then $\sigma=\sigma_\alpha$ (and $P=P_\alpha$).

Comment: Hmm ... I see the case of dimension 1 is trivial, but I fail to see how to conclude from one dimesnion to a higher one. For such an induction step, one would invoke the theorem (for a smaller dimensional space) to either a subspace or a quotient of the space under consideration; but for all plausible choice of those (span of $\alpha$, $P$, $P_\alpha$) one runs into the trouble that the set of assumptions do not carry over to that smaller space, as far as I can see. But maybe I overlook something.